# Proving $\text{P}(E_1 \cap E_2 | S) = \text{P}(E_1 | S) \cdot \text{P}(E_2 | S)$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

My discrete math text says, if $E_1$ and $E_2$ are independent events, and $E_1 | S$ and $E_2 | S$ are independent events, then $\text{P}(E_1 \cap E_2 | S) = \text{P}(E_1 | S) \cdot \text{P}(E_2 | S)$. But, what's the proof?

Comment: if $E_1$ and $E_2$ are...?

Comment: @AlanH _independent events_. Edited. Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand what independent mean ?

Comment: What is the definition of "$E | S$"? Your text really says this is an event??

Comment: @Did $E|S$ means conditional probability of $E$ given $S$. Yes, my text says exactly this. This is actually problem 23 of chapter 6.3 from Rosen's _Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications_ 6th edition.

Comment: *E|S means conditional probability of E given S. Yes, my text says exactly this*... Well, it should not. And the text of your question says something different since you write that E|S is an event. Make up your mind... In any case, the conditional probability of E given S is a **number**, usually denoted by P(E|S), not an **event**.

Comment: Well I got your point. This distinction is important of course. But, does it have anything to do with the solution to this problem?

Comment: yes, and giving the correct statement of the problem is also important, if you expect an answer.

Comment: *does it have anything to do with the solution to this problem?*... Sorry? Of course, it has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditional probabilities are defined by

$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$ (where you assume $P(B)>0$).

Two events $A,B$ are called independent, if $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.

**If** your text says that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are independent conditionally on $S$, then that simply means that they are independent w.r.t. the probability $P(\cdot|S)$, i.e. the relation that you want to prove,

$P(E_1\cap E_2|S)=P(E_1|S)P(E_2|S)$.

**If** your text says that **all three** events $E_1,E_2,S$ are independent (and $P(S)>0$), then you have

$P(E_1\cap E_2|S) =\frac{P(E_1\cap E_2\cap S)}{P(S)}=\frac{P(E_1)P(E_2)P(S)}{P(S)}=\frac{P(E_1)P(S)}{P(S)}\frac{P(E_2)P(S)}{P(S)}=\frac{P(E_1\cap S)}{P(S)}\frac{P(E_2\cap S)}{P(S)}=P(E_1|S)P(E_2|S)$

Please go back and read what exactly your text says. Then it should be easy to figure out the answer.

Comment: The problem statement clearly reads _"...Assuming that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are independent events and that $E_1 | S$ and $E_2 | S$ are independent events,..."_. But, in the solution to the problem it reads _"...Because of the assumed independence of $E_1$, $E_2$, and $S$, we have $P(E_1 \cap E_2 | S) = P(E_1 | S) \cdot P(E_2 | S)$,..."_. Now, it is clear $E_1$, $E_2$, and $S$ are independent actually; the text never said $E_1$ and $E_2$ are independent conditionally on $S$. So your second solution is the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: I doubt very much that anybody would use the mysterious statement in your question to mean that $(E_1,E_2,S)$ are independent.